# Is there a name for matrix product with reversed indices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

The typical matrix product is as follows:
$$ (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m A_{ik}B_{kj}\,. $$

Is there a name or characterization for one such as 
 $$(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m A_{ki}B_{jk}\,? $$
Furthermore, what can be said about the matrix vector product
 $$ (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{b})_{i} = \sum_{k=1}^m A_{ki}b_{k}\,? $$
Is there any way to express the above matrix-vector product in terms of traditional linear algebra?

Comment: Great questions. The beginner's mind is a precious thing.

Comment: Agreed, this is a really good question! It is not trivial but amazing that your formulas turn out to be $A^TB^T$ and $A^TB$.

Comment: @EliRose why is this not trivial? It's pretty much by definition of transposition.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your second formula is just $A^tB^t$ and your third one $A^tb$, where the $(\hskip1ex)^t$ means [transposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)

Comment: (Also, note that $\;\;\; A^tB^t \: = \: (BA)^t \:\:\:\:$.) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 6):

There is not much new, unfortunately, if you know what the transpose of matrix is.

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A} = (A)_{ij}$ the transpose of a matrix $\mathbf{A}^{\intercal}$ is defined by $\mathbf{A}^{\intercal} = (A)_{ji}$.  Intuitively the transpose of a matrix is found by reflecting the matrix across the line through the diagonal coefficients $i = j$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose.

With this in mind your first alternate version of multiplication can be written as $\sum_{k=1}^m A_{ki}B_{jk} = \mathbf{A}^\intercal\mathbf{B}^\intercal $.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ki} B_{jk} = \sum_{k=1}^n  B_{jk} A_{ki} = (BA)_{ji} = (BA)^\intercal = A^\intercal B^\intercal
$$
and
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^m A_{ki}b_{k} =  \sum_{k=1}^m A_{ik}^{\intercal} b_{k} = A^{\intercal} b
$$